# username not being accepted?

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

In the below code Username field is giving an error as shown in the pic not sure why please help??[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NCLAJ.png)

The picture gives the description of the error message that is being received
[image]

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
EditText text;
ParseUser a;
EditText text2;
public void Onclick(View view)
{
    text=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
    text2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    if(view.getId()==R.id.button)
    {
        ParseUser.logInInBackground(text.getText().toString(), text2.getText().toString(), new LogInCallback() {
            @Override
            public void done(ParseUser user, ParseException e) {
                if(user!=null)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Logged in", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"invalid username or password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
    if(view.getId()==R.id.button2)
    {
     a=new ParseUser();
        a.signUpInBackground(new SignUpCallback() {
            @Override
            public void done(ParseException e) {
                if(e==null)
                {
                    a.setUsername(text.getText().toString());
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "user signed in", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    a.setPassword(text2.getText().toString());
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Already user", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,e.getMessage().substring(e.getMessage().indexOf(" ")), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
   // ParseAnalytics.trackAppOpenedInBackground(getIntent());
}
```

Comment: which button did you click? button 1 or button 2? if it is button 2, it does make sense.

Comment: button 2 which is the signup button

Comment: But why does it not make sense??

Comment: `signUpInBackground` method in `ParseUser` might have provided some validation for `username` input which in turn might be throwing the error *`username cannot be missing or blank`*

Comment: signUpInBackground check whether username is null in the background

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upon clicking button2, the a.signUpInBackground() does a checking in background which noticed that the username is empty.

You should populate the username and password before the a.signUpinBackground() and not during Callback ( which will be only run once you finish sign up ), as described in http://docs.parseplatform.org/android/guide/#users, sample as below :

```
ParseUser user = new ParseUser();
user.setUsername("my name"); //in your case, text.getText().toString()
user.setPassword("my pass"); //in your case, text2.getText().toString()  
user.setEmail("email@example.com");

// other fields can be set just like with ParseObject
user.put("phone", "650-253-0000");

user.signUpInBackground(new SignUpCallback() {
public void done(ParseException e) {
   if (e == null) {
     // Hooray! Let them use the app now.
   } else {
     // Sign up didn't succeed. Look at the ParseException
     // to figure out what went wrong
   }
 }
});
```